# Reaction of NaOD/D2O with semicarbazone

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds, nucleophilic-substitution

> [image]

[image]
I managed to solve the question till D but I'm stuck at the last reaction.
I tried to find its solution and the source suggest it as[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Upto (D) you are correct** From there it's :[image]

Comment: I'm not so sure about that four-membered transition state.

Comment: @AmanChande Why base don't abstract H+ from -NH2 as in case of Hoffmann bromamide degradation reaction?

Comment: In your question NaOD/D2O is given in excess so we have high concentration of OD- which attacks rather than extracting a proton. If it was Dil. NaOD then it will extract proton. THATS THE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN CANNIZARO AND ALDOL CONDENSATION RXN ( conc. NaOH and Dil. NaOH)

Comment: @Aman Chande: What do you mean by "attacks rather than extracting a proton"? Are you implying that under strong basic conditions H/D exchange doesn't occur but it does in dilute base? Not from my perspective.

Comment: It will be through tuotomerism

Answer (score 1):

Upto D) you are absolutely correct. Now observe carefully. In D) you have imine groups as well as amide groups. **Under basic conditions imines don't hydrolyse, but amides can undergo hydrolysis**. So, the amide parts will hydrolyse and as the reagents are in excess, you will get the end product as 
 [image]

Comment: your answer also makes sense but the book sugest the above one.

Comment: But as I know, hydrolysis of imines are possible in acidic medium mainly.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I reffered frm book and conclude d.. [image]

Comment: nice quote :)...